# ¿Qué se entiende por "jotero" en México?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, méxico, significado

Leyendo [una noticia](http://www.elmundo.es/f5/comparte/2016/12/08/58485a23e2704ee81b8b463a.html) en la prensa he encontrado esto en los comentarios de la misma:

[image]

Y entonces me surge la pregunta, **¿qué se entiende en México por "jotero"?**

El DRAE solo recoge en ["jotero"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MXqjlpw) la acepción relacionada con el baile de la jota:

> 1. m. y f. Persona que canta, baila o compone jotas.

pero el comentario me da a entender que en México (y quizá otros paises) la palabra tenga una acepción distinta de caracter despectivo.

Comment: ¡Qué alegría verte de nuevo por aquí, Diego!

Comment: @fedorqui, gracias. Si, la verdad es que he estado desaparecido durante una temporada bien larga...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La palabra 'Jotero' varía por región, por ejemplo en la Ciudad de México y parte del norte de la república mexicana se entiende como un bar gay.

Comment: Una busqueda en google confirma esto (al buscar por `jotero` y `mexico` no me salia casi nada, pero al incluir `gay` se confirma que esta respuesta es correcta)

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/?id=MXrydSr

Comment: @Diego Cuidado con esta palabra por que es despectiva con personas que no conozcas.